# How to use CSS id selector?

Tags: html, css

I am a total beginner to web development. There seems to be an issue with my code since the CSS id selector is not working:

```css
li {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

h3 {
  background: green;
}

#special {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>Todo List</h3>

<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="walkRusty"> Walk Rusty</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="buyGroceries">Buy Groceries</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="cssVideos" id="special">Finish CSS Videos</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect setting the `color` of a *checkbox* to do?

Comment: If you want to make the text green you need to apply the id to the <li> and not the checkbox. You won't be able target the parent li based on a child's attributes until CSS4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `input` element (checkbox) under `li` tag doesn't have the text you wish to style through the special ID. The text '**Finish CSS Videos**' comes under `li` tag. The ID therefore needs to be assigned to the corresponding `li` tag:

```
<li id="special"> <input type="checkbox" name="cssVideos" >Finish CSS Videos</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `id=special` inside `li`.

```css
li {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

h3 {
  background: green;
}

#special {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>Todo List</h3>

<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="walkRusty"> Walk Rusty</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="buyGroceries">Buy Groceries</li>
  <li id="special"> <input type="checkbox" name="cssVideos" >Finish CSS Videos</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id is actually applied to the the checkbox. If you want to change the color of text, apply the id on li, not on input. Besides that, use labels for input instead of li text.

```css
li {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

h3 {
  background: green;
}

#special {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>Todo List</h3>

<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="walkRusty"> Walk Rusty</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="buyGroceries">Buy Groceries</li>
  <li id="special"> <input type="checkbox" name="cssVideos" id="special">Finish CSS Videos</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying *#special* on the input tag but not on the text. If you wanted to apply the tag on text i.e Finish CSS Videos then you have to close it in another tag.

HTML

#### Todo List

```
<ul>
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="walkRusty"> Walk Rusty</li>
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="buyGroceries">Buy Groceries</li>
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="cssVideos">
    <span id="special">Finish CSS Videos</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
    border: 3px solid red;
}

h3{
    background: green;
}

#special{
    color: green;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kdsacwz